# Spring @cacheable on @Repository which implements interface - 'no qualifying bean...'

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm using Java 8, and spring boot starter 1.3.0

I have set up cache which works on a class annotated with @Repository.

Once I do an '.. implements IArgh {...' on the class my spring boot application is no longer able to load.

Here's the class that is able to function with caching:

```
// this 'works', i.e. application loads and triggers the cache on subsequent 
// requests

// File: ArghRepo.java
@Repository
public class ArghRepo {

    @Cacheable(value = "test", cacheManager = "springCM")
    public String testString(String test) {
        System.out.println("Cache is not hit: " + test);
        return test;
    }
}
```

-- whenever I use the class with an '..implements..', it breaks and the spring boot application fails
    saying it could not inject the 'ArghRepo' wherever it needs to.

```
// this fails, and the application is not able to load, saying that it's not able to inject ArghRepo:

// File: ArghRepo.java
@Repository
public class ArghRepo implements IArgh {

@Cacheable(value = "test", cacheManager = "springCM")
public String testString(String test) {
    System.out.println("Cache is not hit: " + test);
    return test;
}


// File: IArgh.java
public interface IArgh {
    String testString(String test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my @Autowired variable in the 'Homecontroller.java' used the ArghRepo class, and not the interface IArgh.

When I changed it from "ArghRepo arghRepo;" to "IArgh arghRepo" in the controller it worked as a charm.